# Imaging Interpolation - creating an intermediate image?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, camera, interpolation

we are having a debate/punch up about image processing and was wonding if anyone could help?

is it possible to have a picture of an object at 0-degrees (front on), and another at 45-degrees, and interpolate the two images to create a intermediate image of the subject at 22.5-degrees?

has anything like this been done before? I'm pretty sure it can be done, my collegue says not.

thanks,

kay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been done for rendering purposes, in order to predict parts of the image instead of rendering the full image. I am only aware of academic implementations, none in a particular product.

There is an inherent problem to this approach however - holes, or incomplete information

If the geometry of the displayed object is different from a simple sphere, there will probably be some parts of it that are not visible neither at 0 deg. nor at 45 deg. that should be visible at 22.5 deg, but which you cannot interpolate, since they are obscured by other geometry, so you are simply missing this visual information.

Just rotate a nontrivial object, like a tea cup or a donut and you should be able to see what I mean.

The issue gets worse when dealing with complex scenes with multiple objects.

There are also several approaches to remedy the issue, like using multiple shifted cameras, trying to detect the holes visually and adjusting the number and position of the cameras accordingly. But none of the approaches guarantees a complete absence of artifacts.